# How to pass command line arguments to thread function

Tags: c, multithreading, casting

I have a thread function and I am trying to pass it `argv`, but I was not successful. Any help?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, fn, (void *)&argv);
}

void* fn(void *param){
    // How to cast here, so I will be able to use it as param[0], param[1] etc.
}
```

Comment: You'll need to pass both `argc` and `argv` into `pthread_create`, but you only have one argument you can pass in.  Solution: package both into a structure, and pass the address of that structure.

Comment: @AJNeufeld: you don't really need `argc` as the `argv` array is always terminated by a NULL poiinter...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Oh dear, my age is showing!  Stupid improvements to the spec, making programs behave more predictably ... http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html ... I'll update my answer, below ... then, waving my cane, "get off my lawn!"

Answer (score 3):

Just read what you want.

```
void* fn(void *param){
    char** argv = *(char***)param;
}
```

Or more simply

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, fn, argv); 
}

void* fn(void *param){
    char **argv = param;
}
```

Since `argv` is a pointer, you can get the same value as original by converting it to `void*` and converting again to the original type.

Comment: How OP is supposed to work with array of unknown size?

Comment: @SergeyA:  By looking for the NULL pointer that marks the end of the array.

Comment: will argv[i] return the ith command line argument passed ? or *argv[i] ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to the command-line arguments:

- `argc` - the number of arguments, and
- `argv` - the array containing the actual arguments.

Since you can only pass one "user data" argument to `pthread_create`, you would need to pack both values into a structure, and then pass the address of the structure as the user data.

```
typedef struct ArgCV {
    int argc;
    char **argv;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ArgCV args;
    args.argc = argc;
    args.argv = argv;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, fn, &args);
    ...

void* fn(void* param) {
    ArgCV *args = (ArgCV*) param;

    for(int i=0; i<args->argc; i++) 
       printf("%s\n", args->argv[i]);
    ...
```

---

However, as pointed out by @ChrisDodd, the `argv[]` array is guarenteed to be terminated by a `NULL`; you don't actually need to pass in `argc`, the thread can just count the number of non-null values in the array to determine the number of arguments, if needed.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, fn, argv);
    ...

void* fn(void* param) {
    char **argv = (char**) param;

    int argc = 0;
    while(argv[argc] != NULL) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", argc, argv[argc]);
        argc++;
    }
    printf("There are %d arguments\n", argc);
    ...
```